# MySQL: Unable to create foreign key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to run the following script, but it complains about a foreign key constraint issue:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS music;
CREATE DATABASE music;
USE music;

CREATE TABLE artist (
    artist_id SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    artist_name CHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (artist_id)
);

CREATE TABLE album (
    artist_id SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    album_id SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    album_name CHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (artist_id,album_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artist(artist_id)
);

CREATE TABLE track (
    track_id SMALLINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    track_name CHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    artist_id SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    album_id SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    time DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (artist_id,album_id,track_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(album_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artist(artist_id)
);
```

The issue appears to be for `artist_id` foreign key in the `track` table but I don't see any problems. This is full error message:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2019-10-20 13:04:42 0x1d08 Error in foreign key constraint of table music/track:
FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(album_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artist(artist_id)
):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for correct foreign key definition.
------------
```

Comment: This is an easily googled duplicate.  Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS The error message tells you what the problem is. What does " I don't see any problems" mean? The error message tells you what the problem is. Show that you met every condition in it & the manual section.

Comment: indeed like @philipxy said the error is very self explaining -> *"Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the **first** columns"*.. `FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(album_id),` requires a `PRIMARY KEY  (album_id, artist_id),` to be [used](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3HGv9yqQmqNm7Xd2VgVt9K/0) or a `INDEX (album_id),` [added](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3HGv9yqQmqNm7Xd2VgVt9K/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your create tables to

```
CREATE TABLE artist (
    artist_id SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    artist_name CHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (artist_id),
    INDEX (artist_id)
);

CREATE TABLE album (
    artist_id SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    album_id SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    album_name CHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (artist_id,album_id),
    INDEX (album_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artist(artist_id)
);
```

The error message said as much.

Comment: Can you explain why I need to add the index ? If it's the primary key, wouldn't an index be automatically created for it in the artist table ?

Comment: It is because your primary key from Album is (artist_id,album_id) ans has 2 Columns. not one like your foreign key

Comment: Using `PRIMARY KEY (album_id, artist_id),` will also work fine -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3HGv9yqQmqNm7Xd2VgVt9K/0  .. as the error explains -> *"Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the **first** columns"*

Comment: mysql 8 throws the same error 1822 as shown in the Question, without the index. it will not create the table.